# Overriding an Obj-c class function in Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift

Either I'm seeing some strange behaviour from Swift or I'm doing something wrong.

Let's say you have an obj-c class called `TurtleHelper` which looks like this:

```objectivec
@interface TurtleHelper : NSObject

+(NSDictionary*)getTurtles;

@end
```

Then I want to override this method in Swift, so I do this:

```swift
class SwiftTurtles: TurtleHelper {

    override class func getTurtles() -> NSDictionary {
        // ...
    }
}
```

The compiler throws the following error at me:

> Overriding method with selector getTurtles has incompatible type `() -> NSDictionary`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The type is probably NSDictionary? and not NSDictionary because the original Objective-C method could return nil, but a Swift method returning NSDictionary can't.

Comment: Nope, same error message.

Comment: Did you try something like this.... override func getTurtles() ->(NSDictionary!){ .... }. And if you know the NSDictionary key/value type then, try with override func getTurtles()->([NSArray : AnyObject]!){ ..... } also. In this case I used the dictionary key/value as NSArray/AnyObject.

Comment: Have you tried returning `Dictionary` instead of `NSDictionary` ?

Comment: Yes tried that:
override class func modelClassesByResourcePath() -> Dictionary<String, String>

Beginning to think it's a bug in Swift?

Comment: You need `NSDictionary!` instead of `NSDictionary`. Objective-C object pointer types are by default imported as implicitly-unwrapped optionals.

Comment: You need override class func modelClassesByResourcePath() -> [NSObject : AnyObject]!

Answer (score 8):

It turns out that the answer seems to be

```
override class func getTurtles() -> [NSObject : AnyObject]!
```

From Apple's documentation:

> When you bridge from an NSDictionary object to a Swift dictionary, the resulting dictionary is of type [NSObject: AnyObject]. You can bridge any NSDictionary object to a Swift dictionary because all Objective-C objects are AnyObject compatible.

Reference: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/WorkingWithCocoaDataTypes.html

Comment: same applies to overriding a method that returns an NSArray. Swift equivalent of (NSArray *) would be [AnyObject]. The types stored in the NSArray is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar issue. Using XCode 12.2 I tried to override a function quite alike:

```objc
@interface AuthService : NSObject
- (NSDictionary *)authHeaders;
@end
```

I tried to subclass it as in the above answer and a lot of optional, implictly unwrapped, bridged classes combinations, but what ended up working for me (Swift 4.2, XCode 12.2) was

```swift
class AuthServiceMock: AuthService {
    override func authHeaders() -> [AnyHashable: Any]?
}
```